# Wso2 IS adaptive authentication clear session on backbutton click

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 IS 5.11 configured with basic auth(login page) and password reset enforcer which will force user to update password if it is expired.

But after basic authentication(login page) sucess if password is expired the wso2 IS is routing to password reset page but on click of back button it is routing to basic auth page or login page but once user fills another `username` and `password` and if that user password is also expired it'll route to password reset page but the autneticated user is still the first one So, first user password will get updated.

So, to tackle this, as I am using SAML for authentication with adaptive authentication, is there any way we can clear context and route back to login page with some message.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIU you are doing a browser back in between the auth flow. Doing the browser back at this point will not go through again via the adaptive script. Even if you provide an incorrect username and a password you will again go to the password reset page. As per my understanding, we cannot cater this requirement via the adaptive function.

The approach described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Customizing+the+Authentication+Endpoint#CustomizingtheAuthenticationEndpoint-Handlingbrowserbackbuttonandbookmarkedloginpage) might be a possible fix, but since this is in between the auth flow, there is a good change that this might not work.

The better way to do is that you can improve the **pwd-reset.jsp** to display the username that was there in the session.

You can get the **query string** and get the **username** param from it.

```
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
```

The above code will give you all the query parameters. You can strip it by '***&***' char and get the username param.

Comment: currently I am doing the same thing but how we can restart the login flow by routing to login page with fresh session because without sessionDataKey param the login won't work, so how we can clear the session and re-initiate login flow

Comment: I think IS login pages can be improved by having no-cache, so that the browser back button will always hit the server side. The server can have a URL parameter to detect that the back button was clicked, by matching a cookie against the current step, then presenting an option to reinitiate the login session from the scratch if the user wishes. Better to request this as an improvement by creating a git issue.